# Sorting items from DynamoDB using dynamic value?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling

I have thousands of items in a table. Each item has a numeric attribute `score`. What I want to do:

1. Given some `targetScore`, select all items where `targetScore - n <= score <= targetScore + n` (I got this part working).
2. Return only the first `j` elements where `j := ABS(targetScore - score)` in ASC order.

Since the table is somewhat large, and will only grow over time, I'm hoping to have a way to delegate step #2 above to the DynamoDB engine. I'm currently selecting all item IDs from step #1, doing the computation for step #2 in process, then selecting the resulting items on a subsequent query.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need step 1 to get step 2. I'm assuming that `score` is a sort key in your setup.

In step 2, you want to sort the items by `abs(targetScore - score)` and take the `j` lowest ones.

Although DynamoDB doesn't have any direct way to do that, the definition of the absolute value makes it quite easy to do. First, observe that `abs(targetScore - score) is defined as follows: It is:

1. `targetScore - score` if `score <= targetScore`
2. `score - targetScore` if `score >= targetsScore`

So the items with the smallest abs are **either** items with a score higher than `targetScore` but as low as possible, **or** items with a score lower than `targetScore`, but as high as possible.

So, you can do **two** separate DynamoDB queries:

1. Query for the first `j` items with `score >= targetScore`, sorted in *increasing* `score`.
2. Query for the first `j` items with `score < targetScore`, sorted in *decreasing* `score`.

DynanoDB can do both queries for you efficiently and cheaply - it involves a `Query` with a `KeyConditions` parameter and a `Limit`, and `ScanIndexForward` to do decreasing sorting. But no expensive and inefficient `FilterExpression`!

Once you have the `j` smallest items of each type 1 and type 2, all that remains is to pick the overall `j` smallest items from these `2*j` items we got.

Comment: How can I do a `Query` without a primary key? Also, `score` in my case is not a sort key, just some arbitrary attribute.

Comment: If score is not a sort key you can do what I said with FilterExpression but pay for reading the entire database... You need it to be a sort key for cheap requests...

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. About `Query`, though. Don't I need to specify a specific partition key in order to `Query`? What I want to do is fetch all possible items (across many partitions) where score is within a range.

Comment: Well, you have `Scan` for that, but that will be even more expensive - it's basically reading the *entire* database! I don't know if that's really what you want...

Comment: Exactly my question. I'm currently doing a `Scan` because I can't think of a practical way to achieve what I want. Should I have a secondary index where everything has the same partition key so I can do the two queries you suggest?

Comment: That's an option, yes. But you will end up with the SI having everything in one partition, so you might as well just put everything in the same partition in the original table... I'm missing a lot of information about your use case.